# Многотабличные запросы MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть три таблицы, построенные так, как на схеме данных.[image: Схема данных]

Я пытаюсь создать запрос к таблице List_tab в скрипте PHP.
Сначала нужно выбрать все упоминания о конкретном пользователе. Запрос, насколько я понимаю, должен выглядеть так:

```
SELECT * FROM list_tab WHERE user_id=$user_id
```

Затем, для этого пользователя нужно показать все соответствующие ему события вместе с данными из таблицы events_tab:

```
SELECT * FROM list_tab,events_tab WHERE list_tab.event_id=events_tab.event_id
```

Как я могу объединить эти два запроса?

Comment: Через `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Три таблицы - это не много. Тривиальный случай

Comment: Если просто объединить, то второе условие допишите ... `where list_tab.event_id=events_tab.event_id and list_tab.user_id=$user_id`. А если нужна третья таблица, так и добавьте ее в from и так же в where добавьте условие что ее user_id равен id из list. И left join тут вроде как ни к чему

Comment: @Mike, спасибо, ваш вариант отлично сработал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM list_tab, events_tab
WHERE (list_tab.user_id = $user_id) AND (list_tab.events_id = events_tab.event_id)
ORDER BY event_id;
```

Comment: спасибо, так тоже работает

Answer (score 0):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
SELECT * FROM
  list_tab
JOIN
  events_tab
ON
  list_tab.event_id = events_tab.event_id
WHERE
  list_tab.user_id = $user_id
ORDER BY
  `date` DESC, `time` DESC
```